# OctoberCMS Create Custom Mail Layout / Mail Partial

Tags: octobercms

I'm using October's [`Mail`](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail) service, it looks nice. However, I can't see it is mentioned in the documentation if it's possible to create new `Mail Layout` with plugins or even themes, I believe storing the layouts in the database is not the best way to do it, specially when developing a custom theme with mail layout, or a plugin with mail layout (which is my case).

Is there any way to create a custom `Mail Layouts` and `Mail Partials` from ground up by code (without the need to use the backend) ?

Note: I'm really aware about the difference between Mail Templates and Mail (Layouts / Partials), it works with me through the backend, I only need a way to bundle them with my plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register mail layouts using plugins migration files as for now there is no way to register them directly from plugin config file.

how you can insert layouts
reference : https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/2000

> you can do same for the mail partial. its model is **System\Models\MailPartial**

```
\System\Models\MailPartial::create([
    'is_custom'    => true,
    'name'         => 'Default',
    'code'         => 'default',
    'content_html' => $html,
    'content_text' => $text,
]);
```

and for templates/views you can put your mail templates in **mail** directory inside plugin's view directory.

reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail#mail-views

here within the mail you can defined your **layout name** which you have inserted manually using migration file. and use it as layout.

> registering mail templates inside **plugin.php** config file.

```
public function registerMailTemplates()
{
    return [
        'rainlab.user::mail.activate' => 'Activation mail sent to new users.',
        'rainlab.user::mail.restore'  => 'Password reset instructions for front-end users.'
    ];
}
```

> **'rainlab.user::mail.activate' => {plugin-name}::{mail.<template-name>}** then provide your subject.

now when you install plugin,

1. migration file will insert your Layout in to database
2. plugin registration will register views which you defined in **registerMailTemplates** method
3. now when you use this template they will use your **Layouts** as you have already set **"layout='your-layout-code'"** in templates.

Your all Layout and template related is now inside your template and when you install plugin it will register your layout and template as well.

if any query please comment.

Comment: For `'content_html' => $html,` if the mail layout is in my views directory `views/mail/layouts/awesome-layout.htm` so to load it it's `file_get_content`, any better idea?

Comment: for now i don't have any better idea, as there is no other way provided by they,  so we need to make our own way.. this is best i find by my self